# Position character based on enemy coordinates in lua

Tags: lua, coordinates

I have written a function here which should turn my character based on enemy coordinates but it's not perfect because it does not always turn where I want it to and perhaps there is a better way of writing it

```
local myPosition = {x = 350, y = 355}
local enemyPosition = {x = 352, y = 354}
local xValue, yValue, xDir, yDir, dir

if myPosition.x > enemyPosition.x then
    xValue = myPosition.x - enemyPosition.x
elseif myPosition.x < enemyPosition.x then
    xValue = myPosition.x - enemyPosition.x
else
    xValue = 0
end

if myPosition.y > enemyPosition.y then
    yValue = myPosition.y - enemyPosition.y
elseif myPosition.y < enemyPosition.y then
    yValue = myPosition.y - enemyPosition.y
else
    yValue = 0
end

if xValue < 0 then
    xDir = "TURN RIGHT"
elseif xValue > 0 then
    xDir = "TURN LEFT"
end

if yValue < 0 then
    yDir = "TURN DOWN"
elseif yValue > 0 then
    yDir = "TURN UP"
end

if xValue > yValue then
    dir = xDir
elseif xValue 
    dir = yDir
end

print("Turn: " .. dir)
```

And here you have some pictures to further illustrate what I have in mind:

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

As you can see on the pictures, direction depends on the higher number. If X is higher than Y (both, negative and positive values) then turn character RIGHT or LEFT depending whether it is negative or positive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
local myPosition = {x = 350, y = 355}
local enemyPosition = {x = 352, y = 354}

local dx = enemyPosition.x - myPosition.x
local dy = enemyPosition.y - myPosition.y
local directions = {"TURN LEFT", "TURN DOWN", "TURN UP", "TURN RIGHT"}
local dir = directions[(dx > -dy and 2 or 1) + (dx > dy and 2 or 0)]
print("Turn: " .. dir)
```

Comment: Thank you Egor really helped me there